# MySQL - if second ID equals zero replace it with first ID

Tags: mysql

Let's say my query returns these lines:

```
Project-ID | Parent-ID
1  | 0
2  | 1
15 | 0
16 | 15
17 | 0
18 | 0
19 | 15
```

Project 2 is the translation of Project 1. 
Project 16 and 19 are translations of project 15. So far...so good. Only problem is that I got like 500 projects with about 320 translations and I cannot order them properly. Some translations are far away from the Project-ID.

Is it possible to change the result to

```
Project-ID | Parent-ID
1  | 1
2  | 1
15 | 15
16 | 15
17 | 17
18 | 18
19 | 15
```

so I can order them by Parent-ID? Then it would be like

```
Project-ID | Parent-ID
1  | 1
2  | 1
15 | 15
16 | 15
19 | 15
17 | 17
18 | 18
```

Long story short...I want to replace the 0 in Parent-ID with the Project-ID....if that's possible within a query and without PHP.

Comment: Do you really want to change the result, or just change the ordering? You could use `ORDER BY IF(parent_ID = 0, Project_ID, parent_ID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the ordering, but still show the 0 parent ID, you can use:

```
ORDER BY IF(parent_ID = 0, Project_ID, parent_ID)
```

Comment: Awesome ! That totally did the job and I can use the 0 as optical isolator between the projects...have my like ! Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

use something like this

```
SELECT     
 Project-ID,
 IF(Parent-ID = 0 , Project-ID,Parent-ID) AS Parent-ID
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY IF(parent_ID = 0, Project_ID, parent_ID);
```

add ORDER BY from @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `UPDATE` query. To know better UPDATE please go [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

Try this:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET Parent-Id = Project-ID
WHERE Parent-Id = 0
```

If you want, only change the display data (without change Parent-ID) you can execute this simple `SELECT` query with `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT Project-ID,
CASE
    WHEN Parent-ID = 0 THEN Project-ID
    ELSE Parent-ID
END
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use an update but thanks for the answer.

Comment: @TZP: Have you try with SELECT?